# without using select class I want to make sure "sam" option not available in drop down

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, build-automation, browser-automation

I am handling dropdowns in one of AngulasJS application and the dropdown tag name does **not** start with `<select>`. I want to check the "Sam" option is not available in the dropdown and confirm. How to handle this without using loops using Java/Python?

Comment: Can you please share the HTML of dropdown and list's items. You can use the Xpath to make sure the element is not present in the dropdown.

Comment: I am not supposed to share HTML here and yes we can go with XPath whereas I need the method/steps to proceed

Comment: please share the attributes of the dropdown div and one of the item attributes so that we can give the XPath.